# Match string does not contain substring with regex

Tags: regex, substring, match, regex-lookarounds

Ok, I know that it is a question often asked, but I did not manage to get what I wanted.

I am looking for a regular expression in order to find a pattern that does not contain a particular substring.

I want to find an url that does not contains the `b` parameter.

```
http://www.website.com/a=789&c=146          > MATCH
http://www.website.com/a=789&b=412&c=146    > NOT MATCH
```

Currently, I have the following Regex:
`\bhttp:\/\/www\.website\.com\/((?!b=[0-9]+).)*\b`

But I am wrong with the `\b`, the regex match the beginning of th string and stop when it find `b=`, instead of not matching.

See: http://regex101.com/r/fN3zU5/3

Can someone help me please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use a lookahead to check anything following the URL must be a  space or line end.

```
\bhttp:\/\/www\.website\.com\/(?:(?!b=[0-9]+).)*?\b(?= |$)
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/fN3zU5/16)

Comment: Nice but it does not work perfectly in a sentence: http://regex101.com/r/fN3zU5/15

Comment: That's better, thank you. But if the URL ends with a non-alphanumeric character, the same problem occurs. I just removed the `\b` and it seems to work with the regex `\bhttp:\/\/www\.website\.com\/(?:(?!b=[0-9]+).)*?(?= |$)`

Answer (score 2):

use this:

```
^http:\/\/www\.website\.com\/((?!b=[0-9]+)).*$
```

\b only matches word endings.

^ matches start and end of string

and you dont even need to do it that complicated, If you dont want the url with the `b` parameter use this:

```
^http:\/\/www\.website\.com\/(?!b).*$
```

demo here : http://regex101.com/r/fN3zU5/5

Comment: Actually, I simplified hehre but it can be `b=87b` for example, parameters does not necessary contains only figures. And if I use `^` and `$`, it does not work if the url is in the middle of a sentence.

Comment: of course you will have to add `.*` at the end to match sentence fully and then you can put $ or ^

Answer (score 1):

You had a look at this possibility:

http://regex101.com/r/fN3zU5/6

`^http:\/\/www\.website\.com\/[ac\=\d&]*$`
only allow &,=,a,c and digits
complete url in group and there should not be a "b=" parameter

if you have more options and you dont want to list them all:
you dont allow a 'b' to be part of your parameters

`^http:\/\/www\.website\.com\/[^b]*$`

http://regex101.com/r/fN3zU5/7

`^http:\/\/www\.website\.com\/(?!.*?b=.*?).*$` works too here "b=" is permitted at any position of the parameter string so you could even have the "b" string as a value of a parameter.

See
http://regex101.com/r/fN3zU5/8

Answer (score 1):

```
      import re
      pattern=re.compile(r"(?!.*?b=.*).*")
      print pattern.match(x)
```

This will look ahead if there is a "b=" present.A negative lookahead means it will not match that string.

Comment: Unfortunately, I cannot do this by this way, I need the regex.

Answer (score 0):

This is what you want. `^http:\/\/www\.website\.com\/(([^b]=[0-9]+).)*$`

Answer (score 0):

Its a simple pattern not flexible but it works :

```
 http:\/\/www\.website\.com\/+a=+\w+&+c=+\w+
```